# Need to print specific items in XML and JSON response using python

Tags: python, json, xml

I am getting a response from the google maps api and I just need to get the distance from the Json response and the XML response. I am having trouble finding good examples on how to do this. I am supposed to be using requests and bs4 modules to do this.

The program needs 3 arguments when ran the first being -j for json or -x for XML.

The second is an origin city and state. Example: Nashville,TN

The third is destination city or state. Example: Smynra,TN

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import sys
import json

funCall = sys.argv[1]
key = "AIzaSyD6-37WvsoTYvlgXKdquv5TRFFwgARvq4w"

def Xfunction():
    x = 4
def aFunction():
    x = 3

if funCall == "-j":
    origin = sys.argv[2]
    dest = sys.argv[3]

    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?
           units=imperial&origins="+origin+"&destinations="+dest+"&key="+key
    req = requests.get(url, headers={}, params={})


elif funCall == "-x":
    origin = sys.argv[2]
    dest = sys.argv[3]

    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?
           units=imperial&origins="+origin+"&destinations="+dest+"&key="+key
    req = requests.get(url, headers={}, params={})


elif funCall == "-a":
    aFunction()
```

Ignore the functions at the top I am getting responses within the if statement the -j is jason and the -x is XML.

If i print after my jason req using print(req.content) I get:

```
b'{\n   "destination_addresses" : [ "Smyrna, TN, USA" ],\n   "origin_addresses" : [ "Nashville, TN, USA" ],\n   "rows" : [\n      {\n         "elements" : [\n            {\n               "distance" : {\n                  "text" : "24.2 mi",\n                  "value" : 39005\n               },\n               "duration" : {\n                  "text" : "31 mins",\n                  "value" : 1873\n               },\n               "status" : "OK"\n            }\n         ]\n      }\n   ],\n   "status" : "OK"\n}\n'
```

I just need the distance text value and I do not know how to parse it from the json or xml.

Comment: You'll need to 1) decode it to str 2) look up JSON 3) JSON decode 4) index

Comment: Have you tried searching using a popular search engine for, maybe, _python decode json_? The first result for me is a StackOverflow q/a about exactly what you are asking. I'll let you find it yourself.

Comment: You're using `requests`, so try `req.json()`, then [read the docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), where that's literally in the first eaxmple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the JSON like this:

```
if funCall == "-j":
    origin = sys.argv[2]
    dest = sys.argv[3]
    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins="+origin+"&destinations="+dest+"&key="+key
    req = requests.get(url, headers={}, params={})
    distance = req.json()['rows'][0]['elements'][0][ 'distance']['text']
    print (distance)
```

Outputs

```
24.2 mi
```

And the XML like this:

```
elif funCall == "-x":
    origin = sys.argv[2]
    dest = sys.argv[3]
    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?units=imperial&origins="+origin+"&destinations="+dest+"&key="+key
    req = requests.get(url, headers={}, params={})
    soup = bs(req.text, "xml")
    distance = soup.find('distance').findNext('text').text
    print (distance)
```

Outputs

```
24.2 mi
```

But you are duplicating 2 (nearly 4) lines of code in the if and elif statements, if you move them to before the statements your code will be better.

Comment: when I add the line soup = bs(req.text, "xml), I get this error: bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: xml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Comment: run "pip3 install lxml" to install lxml or change the line 'soup = bs(req.text, "xml")' to 'soup = bs(req.text, "html.parser")' to use the default parser which would be a quick fix but not as good.